# Standard way of allowing general XML data

Tags: programming-practices, xml, validation

I'm writing a data gathering and reporting application that takes XML files as input, which will then be read, processed, and stored in a strongly-typed database. For example, an XML file for a "Job" might look like this:

```
<Data type="Job">
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <JobName>MyJob</JobName>
    <StartDate>04/07/2012 10:45:00 AM</StartDate>
    <Files>
        <File name="a.jpeg" path="images\" />
        <File name="b.mp3" path="music\mp3\" />
    </Files>
</Data>
```

I'd like to use a schema to have a standard format for these input files (depending on what type of data is being used, for example "Job", "User", "View"), but I'd also like to not fail validation if there is extra data provided.

For example, perhaps a Job has additional properties such as "IsAutomated", "Requester", "EndDate", and so on. I don't particularly care about these extra properties. If they are included in the XML, I'll simply ignore them when I'm processing the XML file, and I'd like validation to do the same, without having to include in the schema every single possible property that a customer might provide me with.

Is there a standard way of providing such a schema, or of allowing such a general XML file that can still be validated without resorting to something as naïve (and potentially difficult to deal with) as the below?

```
<Data type="Job">
    <Data name="ID">12345</Data>
    . . .
    <Data name="Files">
        <Data name="File">
            <Data name="Filename">a.jpeg</Data>
            <Data name="path">images</Data>
        . . .
    </Data>
</Data>
```

Comment: Have you looked at XSD?

Answer (score 1):

XSD is the way to go if your file format is XML -- this is exactly the sort of task XSD is meant for and it really does shine in this space.

To handle your optional elements you can do two things. The first is to define them as optional attributes using `minOccours="0"`. If you've got something more complex going on you could also use the `processContents="lax"` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on something similar, and I've settled with using a `JSON` file on the server that describes what type of elements/attributes are allowed.

When a user uploads a XML file, it can be compared to the data file on the server through a script, and elements or attributes with improper syntax can be rejected.

As far as a standard way of doing this, I'm not aware of any, though this method has been working quite well for me so far.

Here's what my test JSON object looks like:

**EDIT**: It's actually an object literal, but whatever ;)

```
XMLTemplate = {
    xml         : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>',
    doctype     : '<!DOCTYPE xml PUBLIC>',
    children    : [{

                   name     : "ROOT",
                   description  : "All xml documents have a root tag",


                   children : [{
                               name         : "GROUP",
                               description  : "Groups contain products, as well as some fields",
                               attributes   : [{
                                               name         : "TYPE",
                                               description  : "What type of product"
                                               },{
                                               name         : "DESCRIPTION",
                                               description  : "Group Description"
                                               }],

                               children : [{

                                           name         : "TITLE",
                                           description  : "Title of the group"

                                           },{

                                           name         : "DESCRIPTION",
                                           description  : "Group description",


                                           attributes   : [{
                                                           name         : "SOMETHINGELSE",
                                                           description  : "some other attribute I don't know"
                                                           },{
                                                           name         : "WIDTH",
                                                           description  : ""
                                                           }]

                                           },{

                                           name         : "PRODUCT",
                                           description  : "Products contain some stuffs",
                                           attributes   : [{
                                                           name : "TYPE",
                                                           description  : "type of product"
                                                           },{
                                                           name         : "SOMETHINGELSE",
                                                           description  : "some other attribute I don't know"
                                                           }],


                                           }]


                               }]
                   }]
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I'd like to avoid having to write custom validation for this scale of a project.

Comment: @GregJackson Fair enough. This scheme was more for designing variable xml formats.